# Why does the assembly code copy the value from %edx to %rcx before adding to the sum？

Tags: arrays, c, assembly, gcc, x86-64

Compiling with x86-64 gcc -Og -std=gnu99 -xc.

In the second line of *.L3* (`addl (%rdi,%rcx,4), %eax`), why not just use the register `%edx` when adding to the sum？

`addl (%rdi,%edx,4), %eax`

```
int sum_arr(int arr[], int nelems) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < nelems; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

sum_arr:
        movl    $0, %edx
        movl    $0, %eax
        jmp     .L2
.L3:
        movslq  %edx, %rcx
        addl    (%rdi,%rcx,4), %eax
        addl    $1, %edx
.L2:
        cmpl    %esi, %edx
        jl      .L3
        rep ret
```

Comment: `-Og` is designed for debugability first, for speed second.  This *probably* means that entire debug-unsafe optimisation *passes* don't run. If such a pass contains a few applicable optimisations that are actually debug-safe *in your particular case*, well, this means they will have to wait until -O2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As 4386427's previous answer pointed out, you cannot mix 32- and 64-bit registers in an effective address.  The CPU doesn't support that.  So `addl (%rdi,%edx,4), %eax` would not be encodeable.

To use `i` as the index part of an effective address, we need it in a 64-bit register.  Since `i` is of type `int`, which is signed, the compiler sign-extends it with `movsx`.  And it uses a separate register `%rcx` so that `%edx` can continue to hold the value of the variable `i`, making it easier for a debugger to inspect this value (e.g. `print i` in gdb).

As it turns out, we can prove that `i` will always be nonnegative in this function.  The initial `movl $0, %edx` [also zeros out the high half of `%rdx`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6), and it will remain zero from then on, so in fact `%rdx` does always contain the correct 64-bit value of the variable `i`.  Thus we could have used `addl (%rdi, %rdx, 4), %eax` instead, and omitted the `movsx`.  The compiler probably didn't make that deduction at this level of optimization, though.

(It is also possible to use all 32-bit registers in an effective address with an address size override prefix, so `addl (%edi, %edx, 4), %eax` is an encodeable instruction, but it won't work since it would truncate the high 32 bits of the pointer `arr` in `%rdi`.  For this reason the address size override is hardly ever useful in 64-bit code.)